# How to change hour of day to execute EJB TimeService

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I want a process to run everyday at an specific hour of the day everyday. I want to use the Timerservice of EJB's but I can only find how to set an interval, not an specific hour of the day:

```
@Resource
    protected TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
public void timeoutHandler(Timer timer) {
    String name = timer.getInfo().toString();
    System.out.println("Timer name=" + name);
}

public void startOrModifyTimer(long initialExpiration, long interval, String name){      
    //Cancel previous timer
    Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getAllTimers();
    for (Timer timer: timers) {
        if (timer.getInfo().equals(name)) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    TimerConfig config = new TimerConfig();
    config.setInfo(name);
    config.setPersistent(false);
    timerService.createIntervalTimer(initialExpiration, interval, config);
}
```

I want to change the timer from "Every day at 2am" to "Everyday at 3am" on runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression schedule)
```

The ScheduleExpression will do what you want.